# Apiary JSON request parameter testing

Tags: json, rest, apiary

Is there a way to test JSON request with parameters with Apiary?

Currently, I have a simple API with a JSON request with a few parameters laid out using the `+ Parameters` tag but that is currently throwing warnings as those tags have not been included in the URI template. See below.

```
# Group Authentication

## Registration [/registeruser]
### Regster User [POST]

+ Parameters

    + id (string) ... Unique.

+ Request (application/json)

        {
            "fb_id": "1097642000199029910322322987867",
            "fb_token": "84uh8dsu9f84932h098dhsfhdsjf94021",
            "fb_token_type": 1
        }

+ Response 200 (application/json)

        {
            ...
        }
```

Further, I am unable to test these parameters in the console provided. Is this not supported or am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `Parameters` is used for defining URI template parameters. When you define an item in `Parameters`, it should reference a field in your URL. For example:

```
# Group Authentication

## Registration [/registeruser/{id}]
### Regster User [POST]

+ Parameters

    + id (string) ... Unique.

+ Request (application/json)

        {
            "fb_id": "1097642000199029910322322987867",
            "fb_token": "84uh8dsu9f84932h098dhsfhdsjf94021",
            "fb_token_type": 1
        }

+ Response 200 (application/json)

        {
            ...
        }
```

Notice I've added `{id}` to the URL. This corresponds to the `id` listed in the `Parameters` section. You are getting the error in your warning because there is no `{id}` in the URL.